# Error Responce When Pinging A Website In Adobe Animate

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

i am trying to ping a website in Adobe Animate and i'm not sure where I have mixed up. The current code I have is below- Any help is appreciated <3

What is is meant to do: ping a website on the click of a button with the instance name HotelA
(I have already got the crossdomain xml file)

Thank You
-Regards, A.

```
HotelA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThePing);


var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ldrStatus);

var url:String = "www.google.com.au";


function doThePing():void
{
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

function ldrStatus(evt:*):void
{
    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        doRedirect();
    }
    else
    {
        // there is an internet connection but the server returns something else (probably something is wrong with the server)
        doFailedRedirect();
    }
}
function doRedirect():void
{   
    gotoAndStop(1);
}

function doFailedRedirect():void
{   
    gotoAndStop(7);
}
```

The Error In "Output" I Am Seeing Is:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on AssignTask_Working_fla::MainTimeline/doThePing(). Expected 0, got 1.
```

Comment: `doThePing` function is missing `event:MouseEvent` argument, [https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an input variable four your event listener function:

```
...
function doThePing(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
}
...
```